# Why is my hamster awake all night?

Tags: behavior, hamsters

My hamster runs on her wheel all night long keeping me awake! What can I do to stop the noise so I can get some sleep?

Comment: Note: I don't actually have a hamster, but I'm told this is a common hamster problem

Comment: I had to move my hedgehog of my room for the same reason. I remember many frustrating nights on the couch because of him.

Answer (score 6):

[Hamsters are nocturnal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamster#Chronobiology) (or crepuscular, according to the linked source). That is why it is awake at night, and therefore there is not much you can do about its activity.

When I was a child, I had a hamster, and I recall this behaviour very well. Our solution was to move him to another room, and put a blanket over the cage to muffle the noise. So that would be my recommendation. I do not believe one should remove the wheel, however, as hamsters need that to work off excess energy that could otherwise turn into unwanted behaviour.

Comment: They also make **silent hamster wheels** which I found impressively effective — https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=silent+hamster+wheel